How to install 'react-native' in WordPress Theme Project?
I was testing some new features on WordPress and saw that the "core/cover" component was using some components from the "react-native" package.
Example file: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/cover/edit.native.js
I try to install this npm package in my project, but I run into some compiling errors:
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/index.js 14:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| // APIs
> import typeof ActionSheetIOS from './Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/ActionSheetIOS';
| import typeof Alert from './Libraries/Alert/Alert';
| import typeof Animated from './Libraries/Animated/Animated';
 @ ./src/video-layer/edit.js 7:0-36
 @ ./src/video-layer/index.js 21:0-26 58:8-12

I use the native wp-scripts compiler for my project.
How i can extend it with loader?
